# Watir Error: unable to locate element

Tags: ruby, watir

I am writing a web scraper with Watir and I can't seem to figure out this error I'm getting. I have an array of text for links on a certain page, but when I loop through it and click on the link and then go back, it breaks.

Here is the HTML code

```
<div>
  <a href="wherever">Text here</a>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="wherever">Text here 2</a>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="wherever">Text here 3</a>
</div>
```

And here is my Watir code

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto 'some_valid_site.com'
array = ['Text here', 'Text here 2', 'Text here 3']
array.each do |text|
  browser.link(:text, text).click
  browser.back
end
```

It executes the first link correctly, but when it comes to the second link, I get the following error message:

```
ruby-2.2.2@gemset/gems/watir-webdriver-0.8.0/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:533:
in `assert_element_found': unable to locate element, 
using {:element=>#<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x1bef61e9aef3c36a 
id="{ad42ba23-8037-a745-8fd7-21955ab49406}">} 
(Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)
```

I am pretty new to this so any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: As you watch the browser do this, does it reload the page on `back` before giving the error? I know most browsers now will go `back`, then call a reload of the page. Don't know if this is a feature of the browser or if web programmers are all setting their pages to force a reload on a back button call to refresh the page (and refresh their ad clicks).

Comment: Have you tried adding some wait time before the next click in case the page isn't loading fast enough?

Comment: @Beartech it looks like it tries to click the lick before the page is done loading but adding wait time does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Watir has a `wait_until_present` method:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto 'some_valid_site.com'
array = ['Text here', 'Text here 2', 'Text here 3']
array.each do |text|
  browser.link(:text, text).wait_until_present
  browser.link(:text, text).click
  browser.back
end
```

default wait time is 30 seconds which should be way more than enough. If the page isn't reloading on `back` you might need to use the explicit URL.